# Where is the frexp function for f32 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am looking for the `frexp()` function in Rust.I found some [references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/std/primitive.f32.html) to an unstable feature of `std::f32` in previous releases, but that doesn't seem work with my standard Rust installation.

I also found [references](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs146a/rust/doc-02-21-2015/std/num/trait.Float.html) to `std::num::Float`, but I cannot get the examples to work either.

Do I have to download a crate to access those functions?

Answer (score 4):

This function has been deprecated for a very long time. This is the commit that completely removed it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41437.

Likely you have a new version. If you are interested, the full implementation is available here https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9ebf47851a357faa4cd97f4b1dc7835f6376e639/src/librustc_apfloat/tests/ieee.rs, but you should likely move to something else.

Checkout for example the `Float` trait [`integer_decode`](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html#tymethod.integer_decode) that returns the mantissa, exponent and sign instead.

Straight from the docs I linked to:

```
use num_traits::Float;    
let num = 2.0f32;    
// (8388608, -22, 1)
let (mantissa, exponent, sign) = Float::integer_decode(num);
```

Comment: `integer_decode()` seems to be something quite different than `frexp()`. At least I don't know how I should use it to compute frexp.

Comment: @B_old From the docs "*Returns the mantissa, base 2 exponent, and sign as integers, respectively. The original number can be recovered by sign * mantissa * 2 ^ exponent*" - the only difference is the fraction is not "normalized", but this can be recovered: easily by `frexp_exp = floor(log2(mantissa))+exponent` and `frexp_mantissa = 2**fract(log2(mantissa))` if I have my math right.

Answer (score 3):

> I found some references to an unstable feature of std::f32 in previous releases

If you follow your link you can see, that that feature was unstable (as you said) and that the [corresponding issue (#27752)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27752) was closed. Therefore the feature and the function is no longer available (remove in [PR #41437](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41437)).

> I also found references to `std::num::Float`

If you look at that URL you will notice, that that is a documentation from 2015, so it's also deprecated.

---

Unfortunately I was not able to find any crate that offers a Rust implementation for you, but since Rust has full FFI support, you can call the corresponding c-function.

```rust
use std::os::raw::{c_float, c_double, c_int};

extern "C" {
    fn frexp(x: c_double, exp: *mut c_int) -> c_double;
    fn frexpf(x: c_float, exp: *mut c_int) -> c_float;
}

pub trait FloatExp: Sized {
    fn frexp(self) -> (Self, i32);
}

impl FloatExp for f64 {
    fn frexp(self) -> (Self, i32) {
        let mut exp: c_int = 0;
        let res = unsafe { frexp(self, &mut exp) };
        (res, exp)
    }
}

impl FloatExp for f32 {
    fn frexp(self) -> (Self, i32) {
        let mut exp: c_int = 0;
        let res = unsafe { frexpf(self, &mut exp) };
        (res, exp)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", (1.3f64).frexp());
    println!("{:?}", (0.3f32).frexp());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95378d3eeab3dc0c914b58b99017cb16))

Comment: It immediately worked on my linux machine, but I got a very long linker error when I tried it on windows earlier. I haven't looked into the problem yet.

Comment: Windows doesn't use the glibc and `frexp` does come from that. You have to link it somehow against the windows c runtime. (Not a Windows expert)

Comment: Good answer, didn't think about using C directly.

Answer (score 2):

I found a Rust implementation of `frexp()` in the [glm-rs](https://github.com/dche/glm-rs/blob/master/src/basenum.rs) lib.

```
fn frexp(self) -> ($t, isize) {
    // CHECK: use impl in `libstd` after it's stable.
    if self.is_zero() || self.is_infinite() || self.is_nan() {
        (self, 0)
    } else {
        let lg = self.abs().log2();
        let x = (lg.fract() - 1.).exp2();
        let exp = lg.floor() + 1.;
        (self.signum() * x, exp as isize)
    }
}
```

Interestingly it doesn't give me the same results as C `frexpf()`, because `f32.fract()` returns negative numbers for negative input. I solved it by replacing `lg.fract()` with `lg - lg.floor()`.

My version:

```
fn frexp(s : f32) -> (f32, i32) {
    if 0.0 == s {
        return (s, 0);
    } else {
        let lg = s.abs().log2();
        let x = (lg - lg.floor() - 1.0).exp2();
        let exp = lg.floor() + 1.0;
        (s.signum() * x, exp as i32)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let x = 0.3f32;
println!("{:?}", (x).frexp()); // (0.6, -1)
println!("{:?}", glmfrexp(x)); // (0.3, -1)
println!("{:?}", myfrexp(x));  // (0.6, -1)
```